# Inconsistencies Casting to Double-Quoted Types

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-12

Using postgres 12.2:

```
select '46ee2794-ddd1-4c4b-be04-82908ff1885d'::"uuid" /*works, uuid is a built-in type, not an alias*/
select '1'::"int4"    /*works ... int4 is alias for integer*/
select '1'::"integer" /*fails ... integer is built-in type*/
```

I have since abandoned the double quotes, but am still curious as to why this behaves the way it does!

Comment: "*I have since abandoned the double quotes*" - good idea. You should forget double quotes in SQL completely anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may seem strange but actually `int4` is a base type while `integer` is a kind of alias, if we assume that base types are stored in the system catalog `pg_type`.

```
select oid, typname
from pg_type
where typname like 'int%'
and typcategory = 'N'

 oid | typname
-----+---------
  20 | int8
  21 | int2
  23 | int4
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Interesting. I had been thinking of "int4" as the alias b/c it's listed as an alias in the postgres docs (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype.html#DATATYPE-TABLE). But I guess that the alias label in the docs column just means "different from SQL standard" ?

Comment: I understand it the same way, `alias` in the documentation refers to SQL standard. `int4` is just internal implementation.

Comment: @klin this indicates to me that only non-aliased types can be cast with double quotes?

Comment: I think so. However, I generally consider the use of type names in double-quotes an unreasonable extravaganza.